# How to show an Activity as pop-up on other Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an Activity A, and there is a button B in the view. If somebody presses B then I want a pop-up which can take some part of screen making the A invisible in that area but rest of A is visible but not active. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

If you want to do this using an Activity instead of a Dialog, you can do this by setting the activity's theme to `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"` in the manifest - this will make the activity appear like a dialog (floating on top of whatever was underneath it).

Comment: somehow it didn't work for me :(. I tried to set up the theme using setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Dialog).

Comment: Have you tried setting the theme to the activity in the manifest instead?

Comment: Perfect!! How do I remove the title?

Comment: use this in the manifest also: `android:label="Custom title bar"`

Answer (score 24):

For AppCompat, add

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert"
```

to the activity in AndroidManifest

Comment: it works, but how to add dismiss button?

Answer (score 6):

The Dialog class is perfect to do that. you can find easy examples [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html).

Answer (score 3):

Just to add on oli's answer, make sure to use the Dialog from the theme you are using in your application.
In my case I did `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog"`

Answer (score 3):

For appcompat this can be used in the manifest

```
<activity android:theme="@style/Theme.Base.AppCompat.Dialog.FixedSize" >
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting theme to `android:theme="@android:style/android:Theme.Holo.Panel"` worked for me.

Steps - 
1. Set theme for the activity in manifest file to `android:theme="@android:style/android:Theme.Holo.Panel"` (This has to be changed to whatever theme is being used). Ex:

```
<activity
      android:name=".EditActivity"
      android:theme="@android:style/android:Theme.Holo.Panel"
      android:label="@string/title_activity_edit" >
</activity>
```

2. In the activity resource xml set appropriate padding and width on the root layout. I have set it to `0` and added a child layout at the beginning with alpha to show some part of the previous activity.

Answer (score 0):

if you are working with **Material Design** you should use `@android:style/Theme.Material.Dialog.NoActionBar`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it programicly

Create Class MyDialog

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.Dialog;
    import android.view.Window;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MyDialoge{
        Activity activity;
        TextView txt_Message;
        Dialog dialog;
        public ViewDialog(Activity activity) {

            this.activity = activity;

        }

       public void showDialog(String message){
        dialog = new Dialog(activity);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_progress_dialog);


         txt_Message = dialog.findViewById(R.id.txt_message);
         txt_Message.setText(message);


       //if you want to dimiss the dialog
       //dialog.dimiss()


        dialog.show();

    }
        public void dimiss(){

            try {
                dialog.dismiss();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }



    }
```

After that crate the layout -> call it **my_dialog**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
      <RelativeLayout 
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"

        >

       <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_centerInParent="true"
           android:text="Hello PopUp Message"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

In your Activity

```
MyDialog myDialog = new MyDialog(MainActivity.this);

        myDialog.showDialog("Say Hello to Me");
```

To dimiss

```
 myDialog.dimiss();
```