# How to hide Title Bar of a pop-up activity

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I created an activity which is shown as pop up/ Dialog by following answers given in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351553/how-to-show-an-activity-as-pop-up-on-other-activity).

I did it by adding these lines in AndroidManifest

```
 <activity
        android:name=".package.Activity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert" />
```

It works well as intended but the problem it shows Appname as title. I want to make it appear as AlertDialog. How to fix this?

I also cant use setTitle("") or label="" because empty space is left where appname was before.

Comment: just add `android:label=""` to the activity tag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android activity as dialog, but without a title bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325018/android-activity-as-dialog-but-without-a-title-bar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this code to the *top* of the `onCreate()` method of the Activity:

```
setTheme(R.style.{style}
```

- The {style} should be ended with `NoActionBar`. i.e. `R.style.Theme_AppCompat_NoActionBar`
- And most importantly, add the code **before** these two lines of code (add it to the top of the method):

  ```
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.{your layout});
  ```

**Hope this answer helped!**

Answer (score 1):

You can simply call the `setTitle("")` function from within your Activity.

Comment: I have tried this but I dont want the empty space left behind.